# TypeScript using part of enum set to define type of variable

Tags: typescript

I have enum that looks like this

```
export enum Alignment {
  Top = 'top',
  Right = 'right',
  Bottom = 'bottom',
  Left = 'left',
}
```

Commonly I will use it in defining interface for e.g. react component props like

```
interface CompProps {
  align: Alignment;
}
```

But now wonder if I can use only the part of this enum, like

```
interface CompProps {
  align: `part of Alignment: left and top`;
}
```

Is there a common pattern for this?

I may think of:

A. `align: Alignment.Left | Alignment.Top;`

B. creating new enum for this task like

```
enum CompAlignment {
  Top = Alignment.Top,
  Left = Alignment.Left,
}
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question `align: Alignment.Left | Alignment.Top;` should work best.

Answer (score 1):

According to [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

> When all members in an enum have literal enum values, some special semantics come to play.
>
> The first is that enum members also become types as well! For example, we can say that certain members can only have the value of an enum member.

This means option A is valid as you can leverage union enums to achieve what you are looking for.

```
enum ShapeKind {
    Circle,
    Square,
}

interface Circle {
    kind: ShapeKind.Circle;
    radius: number;
}

interface Square {
    kind: ShapeKind.Square;
    sideLength: number;
}

let c: Circle = {
    kind: ShapeKind.Square,
    //    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Error!
    radius: 100,
}
```